# Socket option IP_MULTICAST_IF with static multicast route switches from multicast to unicast MAC addressing

Tags: c, linux, sockets, multicast, multicastsocket

I would like experts' advice on the usage of the socket option IP_MULTICAST_IF ("set multicast interface") combined with static multicast routes.

On a LAN, a multicast IP datagram is commonly sent in a multicast Ethernet frame (IP/MAC multicast destination address mapping). On a multi-homed Linux system (kernel 5.11), I have noticed that the socket option `IP_MULTICAST_IF` modifies the behavior as follow:

- Without static route, the multicast IP datagram is always sent in a multicast Ethernet frame, with or without `IP_MULTICAST_IF`.
- With a static route, without `IP_MULTICAST_IF`, the multicast IP datagram is sent in a multicast Ethernet frame.
- With a static route, with `IP_MULTICAST_IF`, the multicast IP datagram is sent in a unicast Ethernet frame to the gateway.

First question: With a static route for the multicast packet, should the multicast IP datagram be sent in a multicast Ethernet frame or in a unicast Ethernet frame to the gateway?

Second question: Whatever is the answer to the first question, why does the socket option IP_MULTICAST_IF switch from multicast to unicast MAC addressing?

The Linux man page ("man 7 ip") is not very explicit:

```
IP_MULTICAST_IF (since Linux 1.2)
    Set  the  local device for a multicast socket.  The argument for setsockopt(2) is an ip_mreqn or (since Linux 3.5)
    ip_mreq structure similar to IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, or an in_addr structure.  (The kernel determines  which  structure
    is being passed based on the size passed in optlen.)  For getsockopt(2), the argument is an in_addr structure.
```

Here is a sample configuration to reproduce this between two Linux virtual machines.

First system, "vmubuntu", receiver running Wireshark on interface ens38:

```
ens33: 00:0C:29:46:B7:CE  192.168.98.3   / 24  -> NAT, default route
ens38: 00:50:56:39:F0:03  192.168.233.11 / 24  -> host local vmware
```

Second system, "vmfedora", sender system:

```
ens33: 00:0C:29:B6:33:8D  192.168.98.2   / 24  -> NAT, default route
ens37: 00:50:56:29:34:37  192.168.233.10 / 24  -> host local vmware
```

We declare a static route on "vmfedora" for multicast traffic, using "vmubuntu" as gateway. Note that the default route for general IP traffic is on the other interface.

```
$ uname -a
Linux vmfedora 5.11.15-200.fc33.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Apr 16 13:41:20 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$
$ sudo route add -net 224.0.0.0 netmask 240.0.0.0 gw 192.168.233.11 dev ens37
$
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.98.1    0.0.0.0         UG    20100  0        0 ens33
192.168.98.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 ens33
192.168.233.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     101    0        0 ens37
224.0.0.0       192.168.233.11  240.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 ens37
```

Let's send multicast packets from "vmfedora" to 239.230.2.44:3044, in the range of the route. We bind the socket to local address 192.168.233.10, which is also the outgoing interface for the static route. We do not use the socket option `IP_MULTICAST_IF` (sample code below).

On "vmubuntu", Wireshark reports this:

```
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.233.10, Dst: 239.230.2.44
Ethernet II, Src: VMware_29:34:37 (00:50:56:29:34:37), Dst: IPv4mcast_66:02:2c (01:00:5e:66:02:2c)
    Destination: IPv4mcast_66:02:2c (01:00:5e:66:02:2c)
        Address: IPv4mcast_66:02:2c (01:00:5e:66:02:2c)
        .... ..0. .... .... .... .... = LG bit: Globally unique address (factory default)
        .... ...1 .... .... .... .... = IG bit: Group address (multicast/broadcast)
    Source: VMware_29:34:37 (00:50:56:29:34:37)
        Address: VMware_29:34:37 (00:50:56:29:34:37)
        .... ..0. .... .... .... .... = LG bit: Globally unique address (factory default)
        .... ...0 .... .... .... .... = IG bit: Individual address (unicast)
    Type: IPv4 (0x0800)
```

We can see that the IP datagram with a multicast destination address is sent in an Ethernet frame with the corresponding multicast destination address.

Now, let's add socket option `IP_MULTICAST_IF` after `bind()`. Wireshark reports this:

```
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.233.10, Dst: 239.230.2.44
Ethernet II, Src: VMware_29:34:37 (00:50:56:29:34:37), Dst: VMware_39:f0:03 (00:50:56:39:f0:03)
    Destination: VMware_39:f0:03 (00:50:56:39:f0:03)
        Address: VMware_39:f0:03 (00:50:56:39:f0:03)
        .... ..0. .... .... .... .... = LG bit: Globally unique address (factory default)
        .... ...0 .... .... .... .... = IG bit: Individual address (unicast)
    Source: VMware_29:34:37 (00:50:56:29:34:37)
        Address: VMware_29:34:37 (00:50:56:29:34:37)
        .... ..0. .... .... .... .... = LG bit: Globally unique address (factory default)
        .... ...0 .... .... .... .... = IG bit: Individual address (unicast)
    Type: IPv4 (0x0800)
```

Now, we see that the IP datagram with a multicast destination address is sent in an Ethernet frame with the unicast MAC address of the gateway as destination address.

And the only difference is the socket option `IP_MULTICAST_IF`.

If you want to reproduce this, see the code below. It takes one mandatory command line parameter: the IP address of the local interface to which the socket is bound. The second optional command line parameter is "-f" to force the socket option `IP_MULTICAST_IF` (not set by default).

Thanks for your explanations on this option.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    struct sockaddr_in dest;
    dest.sin_family = AF_INET;
    dest.sin_port = htons(3044);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, "239.230.2.44", &dest.sin_addr);

    struct sockaddr_in local;
    local.sin_family = AF_INET;
    local.sin_port = 0;
    local.sin_addr.s_addr = 0;

    int use_mcast_if = 0;

    for (int arg = 1; arg < argc; ++arg) {
        if (strcmp(argv[arg], "-f") == 0) {
            use_mcast_if = 1;
        }
        else if (inet_pton(AF_INET, argv[arg], &local.sin_addr) != 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "invalid local address: %s\n", argv[arg]);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }

    const int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    if (sock < 0) {
        perror("socket()");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    
    if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&local, sizeof(local)) < 0) {
        perror("bind()");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (use_mcast_if && setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_MULTICAST_IF, &local.sin_addr, sizeof(local.sin_addr)) < 0) {
        perror("setsockopt(IP_MULTICAST_IF)");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    const int data = 0x12345678;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        sendto(sock, &data, sizeof(data), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&dest, sizeof(dest));
    }

    close(sock);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux doesn't normally handle multicast routing without special software such as mrouted or pimd.  I tried this on a CentOS 7 VM (3.10 kernel) and saw unicast MAC addresses with the static route whether or not I used `IP_MULTICAST_IF`.

The following post on ServerFault goes into this in more detail:

https://serverfault.com/questions/814259/use-ip-route-add-to-add-multicast-routes-to-multiple-interfaces

TL;DR -- Don't use static multicast routes.  Stick with setting `IP_MULTICAST_IF`.